Substituting solution into an equation in a module
I have this model which gives me list as an output

calculateMasses[\[CapitalGamma]2_, equation_, massExpression1_, 
  massExpression2_] := 
 Module[{numericalSolutions2, solN2, mass1solN21, mass2solN21, 
   mass1solN22, mass2solN22, sortedMassList1, sortedMassList2, 
   finalSubList, finalList, decay1, decay2}, 
  numericalSolutions2 = 
   Solve[{equation, -90 Degree <= \[Theta]1 <= 90 Degree}, \[Theta]1, 
    Reals];
  solN2 = numericalSolutions2 /. a_?NumericQ :> a/Degree // N;
  mass1solN21 = massExpression1 /. \[Theta]1 -> solN2[[1, 1, 2]];
  mass2solN21 = massExpression2 /. \[Theta]1 -> solN2[[1, 1, 2]];
  mass1solN22 = massExpression1 /. \[Theta]1 -> solN2[[2, 1, 2]];
  mass2solN22 = massExpression2 /. \[Theta]1 -> solN2[[2, 1, 2]];
  decay1 = ((0.001838254898110461*Cos[solN2[[1, 1, 2]]] + 
        0.00037318681678046636*Sin[solN2[[1, 1, 2]]])^2)*10^6;
  decay2 = ((0.001838254898110461*Cos[solN2[[2, 1, 2]]] + 
        0.00037318681678046636*Sin[solN2[[2, 1, 2]]])^2)*10^6;
  sortedMassList1 = Sort[{mass1solN21, mass2solN21}];
  sortedMassList2 = Sort[{mass1solN22, mass2solN22}];
  finalSubList = {{{\[CapitalGamma]2*10^6, decay1, solN2[[1, 1, 2]], 
      sortedMassList1[[1]], 
      sortedMassList1[[2]]}, {\[CapitalGamma]2*10^6, decay2, 
      solN2[[2, 1, 2]], sortedMassList2[[1]], 
      sortedMassList2[[2]]}}};
  finalList = {{\[CapitalGamma]2*10^6, decay1, solN2[[1, 1, 2]], 
     sortedMassList1[[1]], 
     sortedMassList1[[2]], \[CapitalGamma]2*10^6, decay2, 
     solN2[[2, 1, 2]], sortedMassList2[[1]], sortedMassList2[[2]]}};
  {finalSubList, finalList}]

\[CapitalGamma]2Values = 
  Range[0.16*10^(-6), 0.35*10^(-6), 0.01*10^(-6)];
equation = (0.00037318681678046636*Cos[\[Theta]1] - 
      0.001838254898110461*Sin[\[Theta]1])^2 == \[CapitalGamma]2;
massExpression1 = 
  7.50713719490569 + 0.12705660371714478*Sec[2*\[Theta]1];
massExpression2 = 
  7.50713719490569 - 0.12705660371714478*Sec[2*\[Theta]1];
results = 
  Flatten[Table[
    calculateMasses[\[CapitalGamma]2, equation, massExpression1, 
     massExpression2], {\[CapitalGamma]2, \[CapitalGamma]2Values}], 1];
finalSubList = Flatten[Flatten[results[[;; ;; 2]], 1], 1];
resultList = Flatten[results[[2 ;; ;; 2]], 1];


Equations like mass1solN21, mass2solN21, mass1solN22, mass2solN22, decay1 and decay2 depends on the solutions obtained for solN2.
The expressions for these equations are repetitive and i would like to give them as input rather than hard code it, like i have done for decay1 and decay2. When i give these expressions as input as i have done for mass1solN21, mass2solN21, mass1solN22, mass2solN22 it does not work.
When i hard code it, like i have done for decay1 and decay2 it works. I would like to known if i can do this without hardcoding and giving these expressions as an input and then solve it for the solutions of solN2.
For
\[CapitalGamma]2Values = 
  Range[0.16*10^(-6), 0.17*10^(-6), 0.01*10^(-6)];

and use the the expression explicitly in the module
mass1solN21 = (7.50713719490569 + 
     0.12705660371714478*Sec[2*solN2[[1, 1, 2]]])/2;
mass2solN21 = (7.50713719490569 - 
     0.12705660371714478*Sec[2*solN2[[1, 1, 2]]])/2;
mass1solN22 = (7.50713719490569 + 
     0.12705660371714478*Sec[2*solN2[[2, 1, 2]]])/2;
mass2solN22 = (7.50713719490569 - 
     0.12705660371714478*Sec[2*solN2[[2, 1, 2]]])/2;
decay1 = ((0.001838254898110461*Cos[solN2[[1, 1, 2]]] + 
       0.00037318681678046636*Sin[solN2[[1, 1, 2]]])^2)*10^6;
decay2 = ((0.001838254898110461*Cos[solN2[[2, 1, 2]]] + 
       0.00037318681678046636*Sin[solN2[[2, 1, 2]]])^2)*10^6;

I get the output
finalSubList = {{0.16, 0.00242437, 23.7885, 3.68291, 3.82423}, {0.16, 
  0.909975, -0.837, 3.13691, 4.37023}, {0.17, 0.076853, -1.22217, 
  3.6707, 3.83644}, {0.17, 0.562711, 24.1737, 3.56695, 3.94018}}

But if i use the module given above i get the error
Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result
The output get is wrong
finalSubList= {{0.16, 0.909975, -0.837, 6.27381, 8.74046}, {0.16, 
  0.00242437, 23.7885, 7.36582, 7.64845}, {0.17, 0.076853, -1.22217, 
  7.3414, 7.67288}, {0.17, 0.562711, 24.1737, 7.13391, 7.88036}}


could you make a MWE to illustrate the issue?

I have edited my question
